# Is this example a bad usage of Idispose?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if my usage of Idispose in the situation below was discouraged since I do not use it to free any resources, but only to reset a temporary change.

So, according to you, is it bad design ?
And if yes, what are the reasons behind your answer ?
(performance cost, absolute ugliness, etc...)

I just found a class that was using something similar and I was liking the idea but also wondering if that was inherently bad or not.

Example

```
Using pos As New ConsoleCursorScope(0, 10)
    Console.Write("This is the first line.")
End Using
    Console.WriteLine("This is the second line.")
```

The class

```
   Public Class ConsoleCursorScope
    Implements IDisposable


    Public Property Left() As Integer
    Public Property Top() As Integer


    Public Sub New(Left As Integer, Top As Integer)
        _Left = Console.CursorLeft
        _Top = Console.CursorTop
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top)
    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                Console.CursorLeft = _Left
                Console.CursorTop = _Top
            End If
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

Comment: You can run Code Analysis on it and it will tell you if it is good or not

Comment: Note that MVC's razor framework uses Dispose to actually write a closing HTML tag; so it's safe to assume Microsoft doesn't expect it to only be used to free up resources.

Comment: Yes, that's IDisposable abuse.  You altered its contract, calling Dispose() is optional and doing so is often sensible.  If the client programmer decides to skip yours then his code misbehaves in a way that's *completely* different from what happens when he skips Dispose() on any other class.  You can write a manual to talk him out of it.